# Cannot override "download.prompt_for_download" value if running on incognito mode

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

From Chromedriver 116 and higher, if you need to download a file on incognito mode, the variable "download.prompt_for_download = False" on the chromeOptions is not not taken into account.

```py
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
prefs = {
        "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    }
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
```

if we remove --incognito args from chrome options, it works fine.
Any suggestions on this?

Comment: as long as you don't specify a profile to use, you are already effectively in "incognito" mode. Selenium will launch the browser with a fresh, temporary profile by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the experimental localState.browser.enabled_labs_experiments=["download-bubble@2", "download-bubble-v2@2"] as shown below worked even for incognito mode

````
    driver = chrome
    autodownload=true
    timeouts {
        implicitlywait=90000
        fluentwait=90000
    }
    capabilities {
        browserName = "chrome"
        acceptInsecureCerts = true
        acceptSslCerts = true
        handlesAlerts = true
        validateTLSCertificates=false
        "goog:chromeOptions" {
            args = ["start-maximized", "remote-allow-origins=*", "test-type", "no-sandbox", "ignore-certificate-errors", "--window-size=1920,1080"
                "incognito", "disable-infobars", "disable-gpu", "disable-default-apps", "disable-popup-blocking", "disable-extensions-file-access-check",
                "ignore-ssl-errors=yes", "disable-extensions"],
            prefs {
                download.prompt_for_download=false
                safebrowsing.enabled=false
                profile.default_content_settings.popups=0
                #download.default_directory=${user.dir}"\\src\\test\\resources\\downloads"
            }
            localState {
                browser.enabled_labs_experiments=["download-bubble@2", "download-bubble-v2@2"]
            }
        }
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

By default Selenium driver should launch Chrome as a new instance in private mode. However, it is likely you're still seeing a download prompt because Chrome does not know where the downloads should be allocated to.

Try modifying your preferences as follows:

```
prefs = {
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "download.default_directory": "/path/to/your/download/directory"
}
```

The directory_upgrade parameter directs Chrome to use the new download directory.

Hope that helps.